# Qt 5.5.1 cannot find libQt5XcbQpa.so.5

Tags: c++, qt, xcb

I am using Qt 5.5.1 Creator on my virtual machine (Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS), and Beaglebone black with touch screen. When i write gui application(only one window with push button) and try to deploy it, i get this error :

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "xcb"
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. bash: line 1: 907
>   Aborted DISPLAY=':0.0' /opt/proba/Test/Test Application finished with
>   exit code 134.

I was searching on the internet and found that this problem is somehow related to `libqxcb.so` library, I tried `ldd libxcb.so` command and result is :

> linux-vdso.so.1 (0xbef5a000)
>
> libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => not found
>
> libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0xb6f67000)
>
> libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11-xcb.so.1
>   (0xb6f55000)
>
> libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXi.so.6 (0xb6f3b000)
>
> libxcb-render-util.so.0 =>
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb-render-util.so.0 (0xb6f30000)
>
> libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libSM.so.6 (0xb6f1a000)
>
> libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libICE.so.6 (0xb6ef7000)
>
> libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb-render.so.0
>   (0xb6ee0000)
>
> libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb.so.1 (0xb6ebb000)
>
> libxcb-image.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb-image.so.0
>   (0xb6ea7000)
>
> libxcb-icccm.so.4 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb-icccm.so.4
>   (0xb6e9b000)
>
> libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb-sync.so.1
>   (0xb6e85000)
>
> libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb-xfixes.so.0
>   (0xb6e70000)
>
> libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb-shm.so.0
>   (0xb6e5d000)
>
> libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb-randr.so.0
>   (0xb6e44000)
>
> etc...

As you can see, libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 is not found, even though this
library exists in part of my program where i Keep my libraries:

> -rw------- 1 debian debian 1140 Feb 9 2016 libQt5XcbQpa.la
>
> -rw------- 1 debian debian 1478 Feb 9 2016 libQt5XcbQpa.prl
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 debian debian 21 Mar 1 12:34 libQt5XcbQpa.so ->
>   libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.5.1
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 debian debian 21 Mar 1 12:34 libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 ->
>   libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.5.1
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 debian debian 21 Mar 1 12:34 libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.5 ->
>   libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.5.1
>
> -rw------- 1 debian debian 602768 Feb 9 2016 libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.5.1

Can any one tell me how to solve this problem,also when I start my application it opens terminal.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application needs `libqxcm.so` which requires  `libQt5XcmQpa.so.5`,`libQt5DBus.so.5`, `libQt5Gui.so.5` and `libQt5Core.so.5`

`libqxcm.so` will be in the directory `platforms` in your application directory.

Not forget to create symbolic links for the shared libraries like the following:

```
libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.5.1
libQt5Gui.so.5 -> libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1
libQt5XcmQpa.so.5 -> libQt5XcmQpa.so.5.5.1
libQt5DBus.so.5 -> libQt5DBus.so.5.5.1
```

For a detailed answer, check this answer: [Deploying dynamically linked Qt 5.7 application on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983936/deploying-dynamically-linked-qt-5-7-widgets-application-on-centos-7-cannot-ope/43988232#43988232)